# problem in file upload while using Internet Explorer

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I have developed a web application that uploads the file from client machine to server. it works well with Firefox and Apple Safari browser but when i try it with Internet Explorer,it sends only the boundary.I have set EncType as multipart/form-data.i am using servlet to receive the file. But file sent by IE does not received at servlet only boundary is received.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not homegrow a multipart/form-data parser. Rather pick a robust, thoroughly developed and well maintained library like [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). You can find a kickoff example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/upload-big-file-to-servlet/2424824#2424824).